# Change the key of an object with one attribute from its values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping, key-value

Having an array of objects with this structure:

```
[
    {
        key: id,
        value: id, name, type
    },
    {   key: id,
        value: id, name, type
    },
    {   key: id,
        value: id, name, type
    }
];
```

The key used is the id. There could be more groups of values for the same id, like:

```
{ 132: Array(1), 243: Array(1), 389: Array(3)}
    132: Array(1)
        0: eqKey: "abc", id: 132, name: "name1"
    243: Array(1)
        0: eqKey: "ccc", id: 243, name: "name2"
    389: Array(3)
        0: eqKey: "vcv", id: 389, name: "name3"
        1: eqKey: "tre", id: 389, name: "name4"
        2: eqKey: "ace", id: 389, name: "name5"
```

My question is if it's a way to "regroup" the structure, instead of being grouped by id to be grouped by type. (Type is unique)

So the final form for the above example would look like this:

```
{"abc": Ar(1), "ccc": Ar(1), "vcv": Ar(1), "tre": Ar(1), "ace": Ar(1)}  
    "abc": Array(1)
        0: eqKey: "abc", id: 132, name: "name1" 
    "ccc": Array(1)
        0: eqKey: "ccc", id: 243, name: "name2"
    "vcv": Array(1)
        0: eqKey: "vcv", id: 389, name: "name3"
    "tre": Array(1)
        0: eqKey: "tre", id: 389, name: "name4"
    "ace": Array(1)
        0: eqKey: "ace", id: 389, name: "name5"
```

Comment: you can not have same keys in a single object.

Comment: No screenshots. Fix the sample in question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient method to groupby on a array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-array-of-objects)

Comment: @hindmost Fixed it

Comment: Really fixed? Now it's even worse. Comply with JSON, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two nested reduce for the outer values of the object and the inner array.

```js
var data = { 132: [{ eqKey: "abc", id: 132, name: "name1" }], 243: [{ eqKey: "ccc", id: 243, name: "name2" }], 389: [{ eqKey: "vcv", id: 389, name: "name3" }, { eqKey: "tre", id: 389, name: "name4" }, { eqKey: "ace", id: 389, name: "name5" }] },
    grouped = Object
        .values(data)
        .reduce(
            (r, a) => a.reduce(
                (s, o) => ((r[o.eqKey] = r[o.eqKey] || []).push(o), s),
                r
            ),
            {}
        );

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, your second code snippet is impossible in JS. Objects must have unique keys.

However, I believe what you are trying to achieve is this:

```js
const array = [
  {
    1: { id: 1, name: 'name', type: 'ab' }
  },
  {
    5: { id: 5, name: 'name', type: 'aa' },
    4: { id: 4, name: 'name', type: 'ac' }
  }
];

const result = array
  .reduce((arr, item) => Object
    .keys(item)
    .reduce((arr2, key) => ([...arr2, { [item[key].type]: item[key] }]), arr), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to loop thru the array. Convert each object using `Object.values` to array and use `forEach` to loop thru the converted array

```js
const arr = [{"1":{"id":1,"name":"name1","type":"xx"}},{"2":{"id":2,"name":"name2","type":"xy"}},{"5":{"id":5,"name":"name5","type":"vc"},"6":{"id":5,"name":"name6","type":"fg"},"7":{"id":5,"name":"name7","type":"ae"}}];

const result = arr.reduce((c, v) => {
  Object.values(v).forEach(o => c.push({[o.type]: o}))
  return c;
}, []);

console.log( result );
```

On new browsers ( Or using a profiler ), you can use `flatMap`

```js
const arr = [{"1":{"id":1,"name":"name1","type":"xx"}},{"2":{"id":2,"name":"name2","type":"xy"}},{"5":{"id":5,"name":"name5","type":"vc"},"6":{"id":5,"name":"name6","type":"fg"},"7":{"id":5,"name":"name7","type":"ae"}}];

const result = arr.flatMap(o => Object.values(o).map(v => ({[v.type]: v})))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirements using `reduce` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on
>   each member of the array resulting in a single output value.

```
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "name1",
    type: "xx"
  },{
    id: 2,
    name: "name2",
    type: "xy"
  },{
    id: 5,
    name: "name5",
    type: "vc"
  },{
    id: 5,
    name: "name6",
    type: "fg"
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: "name7",
    type: "ae"
  }
];

const result = data.reduce(function(r, a) {
  r[a.type] = r[a.type] || [];
  r[a.type].push(a);
  return r;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```